# Ubuntu script to compile multiple java files?

Tags: java, linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I understand the command would be `javac file_name.java` but how would I put together a shell script which could compile several java files?

I was also thinking about copying the files, which I presume I just use `cp` and absolute file path referencing.

Comment: The usual way is to use a build tool like `make` or `ant`.

Comment: Why do not you use maven? (http://maven.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .sh file and add the following contents. Make the file as executable and run it.
(Specify the complete path along with the file name)

```
#! /bin/sh
javac sample.java
```

Comment: This will recompile every script each time called, which is less than efficient.

Comment: If I wanted to copy my java file into the location where javac is located, how do I make sure each time I copy my java file it overwrites the previous version? Is there an argument for the cp command?

Comment: cp will overwrite if file exists. And Why do you want to copy the file to your javac location. just add the java/bin to your environment and you can use javac anywhere.

Comment: @AkhilDev I am a bit of a newbie to Unix, can you please explain how I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this script: `compile_java_files.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

typeset -r JAVA_FILES_DIR=$(cd full_path_to_java_files 2>/dev/null ; pwd)   # JAVA FILES DIRECTORY

LOG_DIR="/tmp/java_compilation/logs"    # Create this dir or use another one

for java_file in `ls $JAVA_FILES_DIR`;
do
    javac $java_file
    return_status=`echo $?`
    if [ $return_status -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Failed to compile $java_file" >> $LOG_DIR/$java_file.ERR

        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Then run your script(don't forget to specify the path to the directory that contain java files):

```
chmod +x compile_java_files.sh
./compile_java_files.sh
```